# TYPO3templating and html tag

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I made site package, on TYPO3, by by official documentations, everything ok,
but only one small problem,
when I watch the pages on the browser, I see the HTML TAGs,
I have not answer,
I tried already done package, 
same problem....
what to do??

[image: HTML TAGS on Templates TYPO3]

[image: Backend content (1)]

[image: Backend content (2)]

[image: File HTML to view content]

[image: DynamicContent]

Comment: Can you add some more information? Which TYPO3 version? How are you adding the content to the template? Could you share the relevant code?

Comment: Sure,
TYPO 9.5.1,
nothing in the template, just add page content.

Comment: What is inside `lib.dynamicContent`?

Comment: As far as I can see this should work. Did you change anything in `tt_content` or `lib.contentElement` in TypoScript or the default template for content from fluid_styled_content? Are you using any extensions to help with templates like gridelements or bootstrap_package?

Comment: I think also that the problem is not in the FLUID_TEMPLATE for the page. Maybe something is wrong in the fluid_styled_content template.

Comment: No I didn't change nothing,
I'm using two different installation and both are same problem,
one of them is exactly step by step official tutorial TYPO3
so, if in the original tutorial I get this trouble....I don't know...........

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? There are multiple. Can you post a link to it?

Comment: Is this one, I followed it step by step,
everuthinhg works good, only are visible "HTML Tags"

[link to tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/)

Comment: And the second one that I used is this : 

[site package](https://github.com/sebkln/basetemplate9)

Answer (score 1):

This always happens when you prepare HTML into a fluid-variable and output that variable directly.

In your case you do not assign to a variable, but you output the result from the viewhelper, which contains HTML-markup, directly.

To avoid that the HTML-markup is shown (escaped) you need to use an additional viewhelper: `f:format.raw`

either:

```
<f:format.raw><f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="..." data="..."/></f:format.raw>
```

or:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectpath:'...', data:'...')->f:format.raw()}
```

Comment: Are you sure? The `cObjectViewHelper` has `$escapeOutput = false;` and the documentation says nothing about this (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/Installation/InsertingContentPageTemplate/Index.html). I just tested it in a 9.5.0 installation and didn't need `f:format.raw`

Comment: It doesn't working!
<f:format.raw> is not valid for cObject